# read consecutive tabs as empty field fscanf

Tags: c

I have a file that has certain fields separated by tabs. There will always be 12 tabs in a line, certain tabs are consecutive which indicates an empty field. I wanna use fscanf to read consecutive tabs as empty fields and store them in a structure. But there seems to be a problem. This is my file:

```
   usrid    User Id 0   15  string  d   k   y   y           0   0
```

When I tried to read using fscanf, tab after tab is not recognized as an empty field and data are stored in the wrong structure fields. What is the best way to deal with is issue?

Comment: Having a fixed delimiter, you should avoid `fscanf` altogether. Read the line with `fgets` and tokenize it with `strtok`.

Comment: @DYZ - you cannot use `strtok` as it will consider consecutive delimiters as a single field, but `strsep` will handle empty fields.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Fair enough. `strsep` it is.

Comment: `strtok` should be removed in the next standard revision. Such a stupid interface :(

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: In many ways it would be nice, but they should also remove `strtok_s() from Annex K.  Either the Microsoft `strtok_s()` or the POSIX `strtok_r()` interfaces would be OK — they're essentially equivalent (but the Annex K `strtok_s()` has 4 arguments where MS and POSIX have just 3).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: agreed! and they should also remove `strncpy`.

Answer (score 3):

`fscanf` is a non-starter. The only way to read empty fields would be to use `"%c"` to read delimiters (and that would require you to know which fields were empty beforehand -- not very useful) Otherwise, depending on the *format specifier* used, `fscanf` would simply consume the `tabs` as leading whitespace or experience a *matching failure* or *input failure*.

Continuing from the comment, in order to tokenize based on delimiters that may separate empty fields, you will need to use `strsep` as `strtok` will consider consecutive delimiters as one.

While your string is a bit unclear where the `tabs` are located, a short example of tokenizing with `strsep` could be as follows. Note that `strsep` takes a pointer-to-pointer as its first argument, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

    int n = 0;
    const char *delim = "\t\n";
    char *s = strdup ("usrid\tUser Id 0\t15\tstring\td\tk\ty\ty\t\t\t0\t0"),
        *toks = s,   /* tokenize with separate pointer to preserve s */
        *p;

    while ((p = strsep (&toks, delim)))
        printf ("token[%2d]: '%s'\n", n++ + 1, p);

    free (s);
}
```

(**note:** since `strsep` will modify the address held by the string pointer, you need to preserve a pointer to the beginning of `s` so it can be freed when no longer needed -- thanks JL)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/strtok_tab
token[ 1]: 'usrid'
token[ 2]: 'User Id 0'
token[ 3]: '15'
token[ 4]: 'string'
token[ 5]: 'd'
token[ 6]: 'k'
token[ 7]: 'y'
token[ 8]: 'y'
token[ 9]: ''
token[10]: ''
token[11]: '0'
token[12]: '0'
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Doesn't that invoke undefined behaviour (crash) when you `free(s)` because the pointer is not the one returned by `strdup()` after `strsep()` has modified it a few times?  Also note that `strsep()` is not a part of Standard C or POSIX — it is, however, available on Linux and BSD (including macOS).

Comment: Uugh.... Yep, need to keep a reference to the start of `s`, updating...

Comment: Thank you for you reply....I wanna read some data as string and some data as integers in the file.There are too many files and i do not wanna use atoi function.is there any solution how i can read this file with fscanf or sscanf?

Comment: @Dhan: Which part of "`fscanf()` is a non-starter" is hard to understand.  You cannot do it with `fscanf()`.  It demands at least one character for every conversion specification, yet you're saying "some fields do not contain any characters".  So, you cannot do it with `fscanf()` or its friends.  Full stop.

Comment: `strsep()` is not part of the Standard C library.

Answer (score 0):

> I wanna use fscanf to read consecutive tabs as empty fields and store them in a structure.

Ideally, code should read a *line*, as with `fgets()` and then parse the *string*.

Yet staying with `fscanf()`, this can be done in a loop.

---

The main idea is to use `"%[^/t/n]"` to read one token.  If the next character is a `'\t'`, then the return value will not be 1.  Test for that.  A width limit is wise.

Then read the separator and look for tab, end-of-line or if end-of-file/error occurred.

```
#define TABS_PER_LINE 12
#define TOKENS_PER_LINE (TABS_PER_LINE + 1)
#define TOKEN_SIZE 100
#define TOKEN_FMT_N "99"

int fread_tab_delimited_line(FILE *istream, int n, char token[n][TOKEN_SIZE]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int token_count = fscanf(istream, "%" TOKEN_FMT_N "[^\t\n]", token[i]);
    if (token_count != 1) {
      token[i][0] = '\0';  // Empty token
    }
    char separator;
    int term_count = fscanf(istream, "%c", &separator);  // fgetc() makes more sense here
    // if end-of-file or end-of-line
    if (term_count != 1 || separator == '\n') {
      if (i == 0 && token_count != 1 && term_count != 1) {
        return 0;
      }
      return i + 1;
    }
    if (separator != '\t') {
      return -1;  // Token too long
    }
  }
  return -1;  // Token too many tokens found
}
```

Sample driving code

```
void test_tab_delimited_line(FILE *istream) {
  char token[TOKENS_PER_LINE][TOKEN_SIZE];
  long long line_count = 0;
  int token_count;
  while ((token_count = fread_tab_delimited_line(istream, TOKENS_PER_LINE, token)) > 0) {
    printf("Line %lld\n", ++line_count);
    for (int i = 0; i < token_count; i++) {
      printf("%d: <%s>\n", i, token[i]);
    }
  } while (token_count > 0);
  if (token_count < 0) {
    puts("Trouble reading any tokens.");
  }
}
```