# Reading tab delimited record using fscanf

Tags: c, scanf, strtok

Data file:

```
Newton  30  United Kingdom  Scientist
Maxwell 25  United Kingdom  Mathematician
Edison  60  United States   Engineer
```

Code to read it:

```
#define MAX_NAME    50
#define MAX_COUNTRY 25
#define MAX_PROFILE 20
struct person
{
    char *name;
    int age;
    char *country;
    char *profile;
};

struct person pObj;
pObj->name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(MAX_NAME));
pObj->country = (char *) malloc(sizeof(MAX_COUNTRY));
pObj->profile = (char *) malloc(sizeof(MAX_PROFILE));

fscanf(fPtr,"%s\t%d\t%s\t%s\n",pObj->name,&pObj->age,pObj->country,pObj->profile);
```

I wrote a program to read tab delimited record to a structure using `fscanf()`. Same thing I can do by `strtok()`, `strsep()` functions also. But If I use `strtok()`, I forced to use `atoi()` function to load `age` field. But I don't want to use that `atoi()` function. So I simply used `fscanf()` to read age as Integer directly from the FILE stream buffer. It works fine. BUT for some record, country field is empty as like below.

```
Newton  30  United Kingdom  Scientist
Maxwell 25      Mathematician
Edison  60  United States   Engineer
```

When I read the second record, `fscanf()` doesn't fill empty string to the country field instead it has been filled with profile data. We understand `fscanf()` works that way. But is it there any option to scan the country field even though it is empty in the file? Can I do this without using `atoi()` function for age? i.e., reading fields by that respective types but not all the fields as strings.

Comment: Don't. Use `fgets` + `strtok` or `strsep`. [Possible dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53494091/read-consecutive-tabs-as-empty-field-fscanf)

Comment: suggest using `fgets()` to read the whole line, then using `sscanf()` to extract the fields.  To determine if some field is missing, always check the returned value from `fscanf()`/`sscanf()`   Note: use the returned value, not the parameter values.  There are much better ways to obtain the integer value than `atoi()`   for instance `strtol()`

Answer (score 1):

#### Original format

The `%s` conversion specification skips any white space (blanks, tabs, newlines, etc) in the input, and then reads non-white-space up to the next white space character.  The `\t` appearing in the format string causes `fscanf()` to skip zero or more white space characters (not just tabs).

You have:

```
fscanf(fPtr,"%s\t%d\t%s\t%s\the n", pObj->name, pObj->age, pObj->country, pObj-profile);
```

You need to pass a pointer to the age and you need an arrow `->` between `pObj` and `profile` (please post code that could compile; it doesn't inspire confidence when there are errors like this):

```
fscanf(fPtr,"%s\t%d\t%s\t%s\the n", pObj->name, &pObj->age, pObj->country, pObj->profile);
```

Given the first input line:

```
Newton  30  United Kingdom  Scientist
```

`fscanf()` will read `Newton` into `pObj->name`, `30` into `pObj->age,`United`into`pObj->country`and`Kingdom`into`pObj->profile`.`fscanf()` and family are very casual about white space, in general.  Most conversions skip leading white space.

After the 4 values are assigned, you have `\the n"` at the end of the format.  The tab skips the white space between `Kingdom` and `Scientist`, but the data doesn't match `he n`, so the scanning stops — not that you're any the wiser for that.

The next operation will pick up where this one stopped, so the next `pObj->name` will be assigned `Scientist` and then the `pObj->age` conversion will fail because `Maxwell` doesn't represent an integer.  The conversions stop there on that `fscanf()`.

And so the problems continue.  Your claimed output can't be attained with the code you show in the question.

If you're adamant that you must use `fscanf()`, you'll need to use scan sets such as `%24[^\t]` to read the country.  But you'd do better using [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or POSIX function [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) to read whole lines of input, and then perhaps use [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html) but more likely use `strcspn()` or `strpbrk()` from Standard C (or perhaps `strtok()` or — far better — POSIX `strtok_r()` or Windows `strtok_s()`, or non-standard `strsep()`) to split the line into fields at tabs.  Note that `strtok_r()` et al don't care how many repeats there are of the delimiter (tabs in your case) between the fields; you can't have empty fields with them.  You can identify empty fields with `strcspn()`, `strpbrk()` and `strsep()`.

---

#### Cleaned up format

The format string has been revised to:

```
fscanf(fPtr,"%s\t%d\t%s\t%s\n", pObj->name, &pObj->age, pObj->country, pObj->profile);
```

This won't work, but can now be adapted so it will work.

```
if (fscanf(fPtr," %49[^\t]\t%d\t%24[^\t]\t%19[^\n]", pObj->name, &pObj->age, pObj->country, pObj->profile) != 4)
    …handle a format error…
```

[Beware trailing white space in `scanf()` format strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/what-is-the-effect-of-trailing-white-space-in-a-scanf-format-string).  The leading blank skips any newline left over from previous lines, and skips any leading white space on a line.  The `%49[^\t]` looks for up to 49 non-tabs; the tab is optional and matches any sequence of white space, but the first character will be a tab unless the name was too long.  Then it reads a number, more optional white space (it doesn't have to be a tab, but it will be unless the data is malformatted), then up to 24 non-tabs, white space again (of which the first character will be a tab unless there's a formatting problem), and up to 19 non-tabs.  The next character should be a newline, unless there's a formatting problem.

Comment: `\the n` is a typing error. Now I edited that statement. My question is, reading the fields and load it to structure object as per the respective types. Each record of the file will have only 4 fields i.e., three `\t` characters. If all fields are filled, `fscanf` itself fill the structure fields associated by the type specifier format. If I use 'strtok` or some other string separation function, I definitly use functions like `atoi()` to load `age' of Person. I don't want to use that type conversion functions.

Comment: A more precise format string, insisting on tab delimiters, would be: `" %49[^\t]%*[\t]%d%*[\t]%24[^\t]%*[\t]%19[^\n]"`; this replaces the free occurrences of `\t` with `%*[\t]` which looks for exactly a tab but the `*` prevents it being assigned to anything.  It would be feasible to add `%*[\n]` at the end of the string to read the newline, but the blank at the start deals with leftover newlines.