# How to Handle reading empty values at the end of a .csv file C

Tags: c, csv

Somewhat of a beginner here.

Ex: 12cx7,14:53:00,0.968900025,0,0,,0,

The end has no value in this case (for this problem the value can be 1-4 but I think the way I read it should be fine)

The way I was thinking of handling it was to handle it the same way I would a double comma (an empty mid value) using strstr to find ",," and strcpy to replace it with a ",-1,". Would I be able to do that with the same setup but with ",/n" and replace with ",-1/n"

Comment: Please work through https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: You may find [A: read consecutive tabs as empty field fscanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53494091/read-consecutive-tabs-as-empty-field-fscanf/53494442?r=SearchResults&s=1|30.1775#53494442) useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just add an extra ',' at the end of the string to parse, so you will get the last field between the last two ','

if the last field is present you will get it, if it is absent you will get an empty string

Comment: This should work in context of the rest of the problem, Thanks!

Comment: @LouisPelletier his is a classical way to not have a special case at the end, I use it often