# sscanf a value after repeated characters

Tags: arrays, c, string, scanf

Hi I'm trying to parse data from string which may have empty data. The delimiter of the string is a comma (,).

**For eg: 123,123,hello,,,456** is a string. and i have to use sscanf to parse each data of the string to a seperate variable, then i will miss the value 456 from the string as per my code:

```
char arr[100]={"123,123,hello,,,456"};
int var1,var2,value;
char hello[10]={0},empty_1[10]={0},empty_2[10]={0};

sscanf(arr,"%d,%d,%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%d",&var1,&var2,hello,empty_1,empty_2,&value);
printf("value : %d",value);
```

The ouput will be

```
value : 0
```

Why didnt it print the value **456**?
If the string was : **123,123,hello,1,2,456**, I will get 456 in the variable - value.

Is there any easy way to get the ouput of value - 456, when the string has repeated commas before 456? I have a lengthy workaround, but if there's a better solution to it, i will be glad.

Comment: Is using `sscanf` a hard requirement? Otherwise why not use [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok), [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) and [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol)?

Comment: Also, `char arr[10]="string longer than nine characters"` is not going to work. When creating a [mcve] to show us, make sure it replicates the problem you ask about, and nothing more. Unrelated errors and problems distract from the actual problem you have.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, i think strtok might work, i dont have much experience on it, and am sorry for that errors, i meant to use array of 100 characters. 

Can you show me or direct me to an easy example to use strtok?

Comment: There is example code for `strtok` in this MS [man page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strtok-strtok-l-wcstok-wcstok-l-mbstok-mbstok-l?view=vs-2019).

Comment: If you need to reserve the number of fields, then `strsep()` is required. `strtok()` will consider a sequence of delimiters characters as a single delimiter. (you can also use a pair of pointers, or a combination of `strcspn()` and `strspn()` to work down the string)

Comment: Using an alternative (see other comments) is probably the way to go. You do however ignore the return value of sscanf. It could allow you to get feedback and handle the failure/success of each part separatly and explicitly. Getting into the habit of not ignoring the return value would be beneficial for you anyway.

Comment: `strsep()` example with `'\t'` as delimiter -- you would simply change to `','` [read consecutive tabs as empty field fscanf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53494091/3422102)